# How can we concatenate 2 hive tables without duplicates based on 1 column?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have 2 tables with the same format: **user_id, param1, param2**, ...

I have to combine rows from both tables, but in a way that each user_id occurs only once. (If some user_id is in both tables, then use only 2nd table row for this user_id)

So far I tried to use:

```
SELECT tt.user_id, * FROM
(SELECT * from t2
  UNION_ALL
SELECT * from t1) as tt
group by tt.eid
```

But it only outputs user_id field. Is there maybe a "first_occurance(attribute)" function for grouping that I could use like:

```
   SELECT tt.user_id, first_occurance(tt.param1), first_occurance(tt.param2) FROM ...
```

Or is there a better way to do that?

PS. Tables have 1-3 million records.

Comment: Use so-called "analytic functions" defined in **standard SQL** --> `SELECT id, a, b from (SELECT id, a, b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY` <your rule here> `) AS rank_ FROM ...) ranked_ WHERE rank_ =1`

Comment: Side note: we have experienced data corruption when using `ROW_NUMBER()` on a dataset with more than 50 million key values. The keys were "sorted" correctly but several thousands of these keys had bad data attached *(as if some memory pages had been trashed by an overlap in copy offsets).* That was with Hive 0.13 and 0.14, on TEZ.